# Getting "There is already an object named" error despite confirming object does not exist

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to check if a temp table exists and create it if it doesn't.
I have run several checks that indicate that the table does not exist, but when I go to create the table, I get an error telling me that it does.

Here is the code I am running:

```
1   if OBJECT_ID('[DBName]..[Table]') is not null select 1
2   if OBJECT_ID('[DBName]..[Table]') is null select 0

3   if OBJECT_ID('[Table]') is not null select 1
4   if OBJECT_ID('[Table]') is null select 0

5   if exists (select * from sysobjects where name = '[Table]')
6       select 1
7   if not exists (select * from sysobjects where name = '[Table]')
8       select 0

9   create table [Table]
10  ([Col1] int not null,
11  [Col2] float not null);
```

Running lines 1 and 2 returns a result of 0.
Running lines 3 and 4 returns a result of 0.
Running lines 5-8 also returns a result of 0.
Running lines 9-11 returns the error "There is already an object named '[Table]' in the database."
The results are the same whether the sections of code are run independently or all together.

What's going on here? Is there any other check that might find this table that supposedly already exists?

Comment: For lines 5 and 6, remove the object name enclosures (i.e. 'Table'). What does `SELECT * FROM sys.objects 'Table'` return? I suggest you schema-qualify names.

Comment: The syntax you are using tries to create a permanent table, not a temporary one.

Comment: Note that if you are really creating a temp table, it is created in tempdb database not the database that I presume you are referring to as DBName.

Comment: I was just using the enclosures as placeholders for this post - I didn't run the code with them.
@JonathanWillcock I found it in tempdb. Thank you for pointing that out. Seems bizarre that sys.objects doesn't seem to include temporary tables.

Comment: That is the problem with overly anonymising your code, to the point where no-one can replicate your problem.  In such a case we are forced to guess what you are doing wrong.  This often means that people will simply pass over your question without trying to help.  So please keep this in mind when asking questions in the future.

Comment: `sysobjects` by itself only refers to the active database of the current connection. If you want to check other databases you need to reference them specifically, such as with something like `tempdb..sysobjects`.